# Cannot use helm upgrade in a gitlab-runner due forbidden secret access rules

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, rbac

I want to use execute helm on a gitlab-runner on my kubernetes in gitlab pipelines.

My gitlab.ci.yaml:

```
# Deployment step
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine/helm:latest
  script:
    - helm --namespace gitlab upgrade initial ./iot/
  tags:
    - k8s
    - dev
```

What i have done so far:

1. Installed the gitlab-runner on my kubernetes with helm (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html)

My values.yaml:

```
image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v11.6.0

imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.com/

runnerRegistrationToken: "mytoken"

unregisterRunners: true

terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3600

concurrent: 10

checkInterval: 30

## For RBAC support:
rbac:
  create: true
  ## Define specific rbac permissions.
  # resources: ["pods", "pods/exec", "secrets"] 
  # verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "patch", "delete"]
  ## Run the gitlab-bastion container with the ability to deploy/manage containers of jobs cluster-wide or only within namespace
  clusterWideAccess: false

metrics:
  enabled: true
## Configuration for the Pods that that the runner launches for each new job
##
runners:
  ## Default container image to use for builds when none is specified
  ##
  image: ubuntu:16.04

  locked: false
  tags: "k8s,dev"
  privileged: true

  namespace: gitlab
  pollTimeout: 180
  outputLimit: 4096

  cache: {}
  ## Build Container specific configuration
  ##
  builds: {}
    # cpuLimit: 200m memoryLimit: 256Mi cpuRequests: 100m memoryRequests: 128Mi
  ## Service Container specific configuration
  ##
  services: {}
    # cpuLimit: 200m memoryLimit: 256Mi cpuRequests: 100m memoryRequests: 128Mi
  ## Helper Container specific configuration
  ##
  helpers: {}
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 65533
  runAsUser: 100
## Configure resource requests and limits ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
##
resources: {}

affinity: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

envVars:
    name: RUNNER_EXECUTOR
    value: kubernetes
## list of hosts and IPs that will be injected into the pod's hosts file
hostAliases: []

podAnnotations: {}

podLabels: {}
```

3. gitlab-runner is succesfully connected with gitlab.com

But i get the following message on gitlab when executing the deployment step:

```
 Error: UPGRADE FAILED: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "gitlab"
```

I've checked my RBAC ClusterRules and they are all per default set to a wildcard on verbs and ressources but i have also tried to set the needed rights:

```
  resources: ["pods", "pods/exec", "secrets"] 
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "patch", "delete"]
```

Nothing worked :-(
When i have done wrong?

Comment: Deployed in the wrong namespace? Seems there is a namespace default and one called gitlab.

Comment: Still not getting it to work :-(

Comment: I have ran into the same error. If you happened to find a solution, please post an update!

Answer (score 2):

I hope I have found the decision for this problem. Try to create clusterrolebinding like this

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding gitlab-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts
```

Comment: NOT SAFE!!! This allows any application full access to your cluster, and also grants any user with read access to Secrets (or the ability to create any pod) full access to your cluster.

Comment: @XPLOT1ON Then what do you propose? We're not all rbac experts

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue by setting runners.serviceAccountName to a serviceAccount I created with all rights in the namespace.

Comment: Happy to hear you fixed it. But can you share your fix? With code?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my step to address this issue:

First, create service account and custom role for your Gitlab Runner:

```
kubectl create sa sa-runner -n gitlab
kubectl create role sa-runner-role -n gitlab --verb=get,list,watch,create,delete,patch --resource=pods,secret,pods/exec
kubectl create rolebinding sa-runner-rolebinding -n gitlab --role=sa-runner-role --serviceaccount=gitlab:sa-runner
kubectl create clusterrole deploy-default --verb=get,list,watch,patch --resource=deployment
kubectl create clusterrolebinding deploy-default-binding --clusterrole=deploy-default --serviceaccount=gitlab:default
```

Then, add serviceAccountName: sa-runner to your values.yaml file

```
## Use the following Kubernetes Service Account name if RBAC is disabled in this Helm chart (see rbac.create)
serviceAccountName: "sa-runner"
```

One you done with it, don't forget to do upgrade in your Helm